# true loading screen on startup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile app that will need a true loading screen on start of the app, because whenever I start the app, it displays whitescreen and loads something online before it loads up the whole app.

After I searched all this time still no answers I got.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just replace the "whitescreen" with some graphic – but that in turn must get loaded as well.

Comment: Just create a splashscreen add some image u want and intergate it with th app..

Comment: I already tried to put some in my xml but the duration of splashscreen is not depending on how fast everything will load.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you have an Hybrid application? The app has an inline browser that displays the HTML page right?
In that case consider displaying a first native page that will be replaces by the browser widget when the HTML content is loaded. I assume that you are doing some network stuff on the background. 
Or
You can display in your browser a page before you are doing any networking and then switch it.

It really depends on your app/

Comment: All I'm tracing is the API I used like facebook API.